# User account user name conditon

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, database

I am using ASP.net with C# to create user records. In the code below, how do I setup a condition to detect if the username already exists.

```
try
{
    Guid newGuid = Guid.NewGuid();

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();

    string insertQuery = "insert into UsrData (Id, UserName, Email, Password, Country) values (@id, @Uname, @email, @password, @country)";

    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);

    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", newGuid);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Uname", TextBoxUN.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBoxEmail.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBoxPass.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", DropDownListCountry.SelectedItem.ToString());

    com.ExecuteNonQuery();

    Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
    Response.Write("Sucessuflly registred");

    conn.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write("An unknown error " + ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: What have you tried already? Also, what DB engine are you using (MSSQL, MySQL, something else)? You'll be likely to get a more relevant answer if you tag your DB engine in your question.

Comment: It's a really serious let-down to your users when you store passwords in plaintext (and against PCI-DSS requirements if you intend to take card payments). Authentication is hard and boring. It's also a solved problem. Why don't you use an existing identity framework instead of rolling your own? Aspnet Identity, for instance?

Answer (score 0):

Put an exists condition in your SQL code:

```
try
{
  Guid newGuid = Guid.NewGuid();

  SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
  conn.Open();

  string insertQuery = @"if not exists (select * from UsrData where UserName = @Uname)
    insert into UsrData (Id, UserName, Email, Password, Country) values (@id, @Uname, @email, @password, @country)";
  SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);

    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", newGuid);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Uname", TextBoxUN.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBoxEmail.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBoxPass.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", DropDownListCountry.SelectedItem.ToString());

    com.ExecuteNonQuery();

    Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
    Response.Write("Sucessuflly registred");

    conn.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write("An unknown error " + ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Please copy my post example and then edit and sent me complete process.

Comment: Why? The query is right there, just drop it in place of the SQL query you have in your code.

Comment: Not understood  how to insert above (your code) insert into my code. so you can post full code. tanks

Comment: How hard is it to do `var insertQuerey = if not exists (select * from UsrData where UserName = @Uname)
  insert into UsrData (Id,UserName,Email,Password,Country) values (@id,@Uname,@email, @password, @country)`

Comment: Minor nitpick, that string needs quotes @ChetanRanpariya ;)

Comment: Not understood.

Comment: @FrankHagenson I would argue against spoonfeeding in this manner (eg: this [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307970)), if they can't work out where this modification would go *in their own code* that would suggest they need a much deeper understanding of the language and/or their codebase first. Or they're a help vampire, either or.

Comment: @Hoppeduppeanut point taken. Must have been feeling overly generous that day.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on if the username check should extend to the entire table, or just this one statement (in which case, Frank's answer is correct).

Depending on the DBMS you're using, you can define a [`UNIQUE` key/constraint](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp) against the UserName column, which will guarantee uniqueness. However, you will need to ensure that all usernames currently in the table are unique before applying this constraint.

Comment: I don't want to use UNIQUE Key/constraint. just using asp.net c# code behind condition.